# treating multiple URLs as a single 'like' object for fb like button

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I am working on a site with a custom CMS that generates URLs based on article titles. The problem being faced by the site contributors is that when they update a title of an article it generates a new URL for the article so all the previous 'likes' of the article are associated with the old URL (where a copy of the article is still viewable) and the new one doesn't have any likes. Is there any way to implement Facebook likes so that two different URLs share the same pool of likes -- so therefore the likes of the old URL will transfer over to the new URL and if a like button is pressed on either URL it contributes to their common pool of likes? Any other suggestions for getting around this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use concatenated URLs? like

```
/url-generated-from-title-id
```

where `id` holds a static ID of the article in your database? you can always strip this last part with simple JavaScript

```
var pathParts  = location.pathname.split("/"),
    identifier = pathParts[pathParts.length-1].split("-"),
    articleId  = identifier[identifier.length-1]; // holds "id"
```

the title can still change but the id won't

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This sounds like it would be a fine approach but I am first exploring if there's any way to do this without changing how the URLs are generated, so for the purposes of this question I'd take the currently URL structure as a given.

Comment: hmm how about sending that title to the server and letting it be resolved there into a static id of the database... do you have unique ids?

Comment: actually you know what I think the way you suggested might totally work since there are unique ids embedded in the URLs. Accepted. Thanks!